# Regular Expression to find pPath_ at the Beginning of a Word

Tags: regex

I'm wondering in general what would be the syntax to find all words that contain the phrase "pPath_" at the beginning of it. I realize that pPath_. finds all words with one character after it, but how to find with any amount of characters? (I'm using xCode find and replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple definition of "word",

```
pPath_\w*
```

If your engine doesn't support `\w` or doesn't have a useful definition for it, you can use a character class.

```
pPath_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find only words starting with "pPath_", you can use a word boundary (\b) at the start. Otherwise, you'll get any word containing "pPath_".

```
\bpPath_\w+
```

'\w' is a word character (any letter, number or underscore), equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]

'+' matches one or more characters.